# What is the most minimal functional programming language?

Tags: functional-programming

What is the most minimal functional programming language?

Comment: To the close-voters, the "minimal functional programming language" seems a legitimate question. @Ishihara, your first question about disadvantages could be regarded as subjective and likely to provoke argument - questions like that are discouraged

Comment: @Paul: Yep, it is a valid question, but only if it is the only question. *Also can anyone tell me the most minimal functional programming language?* does not event match the title of question... currently the "question" is some kind of weird mixture...

Comment: Scheme is a very simple functional programming language. The basics can be picked up very quickly. I'm not sure if it is the "most minimal" though.

Comment: @Fexi, yep, needs rewording by the OP

Comment: The "minimal" question is legitimate, if somewhat vague. Disadvantages of Haskell *could* be a valid question, if given a more specific context. As it stands, my answer on that would be "the main disadvantage of Haskell is that people ask poorly-defined questions on SO about its disadvantages".

Comment: possibly related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284875/why-is-haskell-used-so-little-in-the-industry/.

Comment: Edited to leave only the "minimal" question -- there are good answers and I wanted to save the question.

Comment: I find even the remaining "minimal" question a bit troubling. Can anyone suggest a precise and objective definition of minimal. Can you defend it against alternative definitions. The original lisp is pretty small.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by minimal.

To start with, the ancestor of functional languages is, first and foremost, **mathematical logic**. The computational use of certain logics came after the fact. In a sense, many mathematical systems (the cores of which are usually quite minimal) could be called functional languages. But I doubt that's what you're after!

Best known is [Alonzo Church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church)'s [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), of which there are variants and descendants:

- The simplest form is what's called the **untyped lambda calculus**; this contains nothing but lambda abstractions, with no restrictions on their use. The creation of data structures using only anonymous functions is done with what's called **Church encoding** and represents data by fundamental operations on it; the number 5 becomes "repeat something 5 times", and so on.
- Lisp-family languages are little more than untyped lambda calculus, augmented with atomic values, cons cells, and a handful of other things. I'd suspect Scheme is the most minimalist here, as if memory serves me it was created first as a teaching language.
- The original purpose of the lambda calculus, that of describing logical proofs, failed when the untyped form was shown to be inconsistent, which is a polite term for "lets you prove that false is true". (*Historical trivia: the paper proving this, which was a significant thing at the time, did so by writing a logical proof that, in computational terms, went into an infinite loop.*) Anyway, the use as a logic was recovered by introducing **typed lambda calculus**. These tend not to be directly useful as programming languages, however, particularly since being logically sound makes the language not Turing-complete.
- However, similarly to how Lisps derive from untyped lambda calculus, a typed lambda calculus extended with built-in recursion, algebraic data types, and a few other things gets you the extended ML-family of languages. These tend to be pretty minimal 
  at heart, with syntactic constructs having straightforward translations to lambda terms in many cases. Besides the obvious ML dialects, this also includes Haskell and a few other languages. I'm not aware of any especially minimalist typed functional languages, however; such a language would likely suffer from poor usability far worse than a minimalist untyped language.

So as far as lambda calculus variants go, the pure untyped lambda calculus with no extra features is Turing-complete and about as minimal as you can get!

However, arguably more minimal is to eliminate the concept of "variables" entirely--in fact, this was originally done to simplify meta-mathematical proofs about logical systems, if memory serves me--and use only higher-order functions called **combinators**. Here we have:

- [Combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) itself, as originally invented by [Moses Schönfinkel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sch%C3%B6nfinkel) and developed extensively by [Haskell Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry). Each combinator is defined by a simple substitution rule, for instance `Sxyz = xz(yz)`. The lowercase letters are used like variables in this definition, but keep in mind that combinatory logic itself doesn't use variables, or assign names to anything at all. Combinatory logic is minimal, to be sure, but not too friendly as a programming language. Best-known is the **SK** combinator base. S is defined as in the example above; K is `Kxy = x`. Those two combinators alone suffice to make it Turing-complete! This is almost frighteningly minimal.
- [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/) is a language based on SK combinators, extending it with a few extra combinators with special properties. Less minimal, but lets you write "Hello World".
- Even two combinators is more than you need, though. Various one-combinator bases exist; perhaps the best known is the **iota Combinator**, defined as `ιx = xSK`, which is used in a minimalist language also called [Iota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_and_Jot)
- Also of some note is [Lazy K](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/cl/lazy-k.html), which is distinguished from Unlambda by not introducing additional combinators, having no side effects, and using lazy evaluation. Basically, it's the Haskell of the combinator-based-esoteric-language world. It supports both the SK base, as well as the iota combinator.

Which of those strikes you as most "minimal" is probably a matter of taste.

Comment: You should save this answer, in case it gets deleted. :-(

Comment: Did Schönfinkel really propose a form of combinatory logic? I've often seen the notion of currying attributed to him, but not this. I've also seen the notion of currying attributed to Frege, but have never verififed that claim.

Comment: @dubiousjim: Currying was attributed to Schönfinkel by Curry, but I think predates both (Frege sounds plausible), making this an unusually intricate example of Baez's law. For his part, Schönfinkel's career was short and full of misfortune; his single paper on the subject would likely have been forgotten had Curry not found it after independently inventing similar concepts. I *vaguely* recall, but cannot cite, that the SK basis was in fact Schönfinkel's, adopted by Curry in place of his original formulation.

Comment: @dubiousjim: To be terribly honest I don't believe Schönfinkel contributed much beyond what Curry independently invented. I, and perhaps others, go out of the way to credit him not merely for the technicality of being first, but out of respect for a man who deserved so much better than he got. Not everyone is given eight decades of life to secure their reputation like Curry, and I think it's important to remember that.

Comment: @C.A.McCann, thanks for all this. In my field, I see history sweeping the facts aside all the time, and expect it's just sadly how one should normally expect ideas to develop. But it's interesting to get more of the real details straight when opportunities to do so present themselves. So thanks.

Comment: iota has two combinators '0' and '1', you can tell because you write your program with both 0's and 1's

Comment: Binary lambda calculus lets you write "Hello world" with minimal additions to the pure lambda calculus https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html

Answer (score 8):

The arguably most minimal functional languages are [iota and Jot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_and_Jot), because they use only one combinator (while unlambda needs two). Here is a short explanation: http://web.archive.org/web/20061105204247/http://ling.ucsd.edu/~barker/Iota/

Answer (score 4):

I'd imagine the most minimal functional "programming language" would be [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Comment: Or SKI combinator calculus. Unlambda is the actual programming language.

Comment: @jetxee: Good point. Forgot those. And I even looked at the Unlambda website two days ago...

Answer (score 4):

**BrainF*ck is a simple, easy to use programming language. Here's a quick rundown.**

Imagine you have a near-infinite range of boxes, each empty. Luckily, you are not alone! You can move back and forth along the line, put things in them, and take them out. Though quite basic, with enough time you can do about anything: http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_bf_inter.html. Here are the commands.

```
+ | add one to currrent box
- | take one from current box
> | move one box to the right
< | move one box to the left
[] | loop
. | print current value
, | input current value
```

**other stuff to look at:**

P" | simplified BF

language f | newer simplified BF

http://www2.gvsu.edu/miljours/bf.html | cool BF stuff/intro

https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list | list of similar langs/variants

Comment: [Boolfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck) is simpler (bits rather than bytes).

Answer (score 0):

An esoteric programming language (a.k.a. esolang) is a programming language designed to test the boundaries of computer programming language design, as a proof of concept, as software art, as a hacking interface to another language (particularly functional programming or procedural programminglanguages), or as a joke. The use of esotericdistinguishes these languages from programming languages that working developers use to write software. Usually, an esolang's creators do not intend the language to be used for mainstream programming, although some esoteric features, such as visuospatial syntax, have inspired practical applications in the arts. Such languages are often popular among hackers and hobbyists.

Answer (score 0):

The [FlipJump](https://github.com/tomhea/flip-jump) ([esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FlipJump)) is a programming language that has 1 instruction, which is: **Flip** a bit, then **Jump**.
The instruction `a;b` translates to `not *a; jump b`.

It might surprise you, but with this language can implement actually anything. For example, a program that prints the prime numbers up to a given input ([source](https://github.com/tomhea/flip-jump/blob/main/programs/prime_sieve.fj)):
[image]

Full disclosure, I created the language back in 2021, with the idea of creating the most minimal programming language. I have supported it since, and created a fully tested standard library for the language, as well as easy to use assembler + interpreter ([github](https://github.com/tomhea/flip-jump)).