# Minimalistic programming languages

Tags: programming-languages

Which programming languages have a small number of keywords and/or a limited syntax?

(PS. Please list languages that get real world usage, rather than esoteric languages.)

Comment: ...and knowing will solve what programming problem?

Comment: Where should I ask this question?

Comment: would depend on your definition of 'small' and 'limited' wouldn't it? At what point does it cease being a useful language and become an esoteric one with such a goal in mind?

Comment: Esoteric languages generally define themselves as such.

Comment: The smallest programming language I can think of is binary.  It has a very minimalistic syntax and lexicon and can do anything that any other Turing machine equivalent language can do.

Comment: After a few years of research, Haskell and Scheme are some of the most usable, minimal languages I have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

((((([Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29))))))

Answer (score 1):

[Smalltalk-80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) only six "keywords" are reserved in Smalltalk: true, false, nil, self, super, and thisContext

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the most minimalistic language that is still in use today would be, [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), but I seriously doubt that could be called a programming language. LISP-family, and Python are among the most widely used languages with less instructions. If you are into expert systems CLIPS is also used for research and game dev. and it contains very few instructions (it is based on logic)

Here you have some more answers

[What is the most minimal functional programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366856/most-minimal-functional-programming-language)